# When to use Dynamic encoding/decoding in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I am new to Swift and a bit confused about Dynamic encoding & decoding.

In an interview i was asked to parse an API response

API Response:

```
{
    "propertyID" : 12,
    "user" : {
        "firstname" : "James"
        "lastname" : "William"
    }
}
```

Use decoding/encoding I was able to parse and output the answer. Here are the classes I used:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    }
}
```

and

```
struct Response : Codable {
    let user: User?
    let propertyID: Int?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user
        case propertyID
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try values.decode(User.self, forKey: .user)
        propertyID = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .propertyID)
    }
}
```

But the Interviewer responded:

"The Networking models could only conform to Decodable/Encodable without any coding keys or initializers because there is no custom encoding/decoding being done".

Please let me know how to further improve the above classes and in general the best practices for parsing json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1: You should have asked interviewer "which properties may be null?" and only make **them** `optional`. You should not make everything `optional`.

2: `struct` has a automatic `@memberwise` initializer, so you don't need to manually rewrite it.

3: You should use `decodeIfPresent` function for any `optional` value you used.

4: Conforming to `Decodable` automatically adds the needed initializer, so you don't need to rewrite it if you don't need to make it custom. **The interviewer's point**

5: Conforming to `Decodable` or `Encodable` automatically adds the `CodingKeys` underneath with the exact name of the variables, so you don't need to rewrite it again **Only if** you don't want to change them.

#### In this case:

```
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "firstname"
        case lastName = "lastname"
    }
```

<sub>I would ask backend developers to change the original json to correct format</sub>

You have changed the non-camelCase to *camelCase*, So it's needed!

6: Conforming to `Codable` gives you access to the `CodingKey` too. So you can use it in custom initializer as you need.

So it could be as simple as:

```
struct Response : Codable {
    let user: User
    let propertyID: Int

    struct User: Codable {
        let firstname: String
        let lastname: String
    }
}
```

Note that you could use `Response` struct as a namespace for the `User` struct.

At last, remember it depends on the needs and developer guidelines of the company.

Comment: step 3 isn't true for optional you don't have to ,,,,,, step 5 case should be like case firstName = "firstname" or he'll get a decode error

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thanks for the detail reply. The 4th point I should not have used init(from decoder) because i am not doing anything custom e.g changing a value and should use the Decodable class instead of codable right?

Comment: `Init` is not required either you conforming to `Decodable` or `Codable`. If don’t need to encode object back to a json, `Decodable` would be enough.

Comment: making the var optional is sufficient